# reference to model a network which nodes handle processing

Tags: graphs, network-analysis

does anybody have a basic reference (if it is possible) that explain how to mathematically model the state of a network. I assume that it goes like modeling a graph that is composed by nodes and edges. I need to handle the process of each node are doing.

What I have already in mind it is:
- each node can execute a set of process.
- the process changes the state of the node.
- each node has a set of states.

So, is it reasonable to say that I will create one graph for each node of my network? In each graph I will describe how all the states of a node will change.

Does anybody has a basic reference of a book that would help me? Currently, I am reading the book "Graph Databases, NEW OPPORTUNITIES FOR CONNECTED DATA".

Kind Regards,
Felipe

Comment: "Model the state of a network" is a pretty broad topic.  I suggest you edit your question to describe (a) what kind of network you have in mind, (b) what you want to be able to do with the model - what kind of questions do you want to use it to answer? what do you want to be able to predict?  what aspects of behavior do you want to model?

Comment: You might want to look at model checking to see if it does what you want.  It provides a way to model concurrent interacting processes and reason about their behavior.  Not sure if it will be what you want or not.

Comment: I want to answer questions regarding the process of the data in each node of my network. I will read something about model checking (Automatic verification of finite-state concurrent systems using temporal logic specifications). thanks

Comment: Sorry, that's too vague for me to give you any useful suggestions.  If you can make your question more specific and focused, I encourage you to edit it accordingly.  Good luck in your searches!

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess is that I can model the state of a network using Mealy machine. With it, I can have input and output events, and output functions and transitions. Do you think it is reasonable the direction that I am going?

Comment: I don't know.  There are many ways you could model a network.  Whether that one will be reasonable will depend on what questions you want to answer with it.  Currently the question is too vague for me to understand what you want to do with the model.  I don't know what "answer questions regarding the process of the data in each node of my network" means, specifically, so you'd have to be more specific and more concrete in the question before I would have any idea how to help.

Comment: thanks DW for your comments. I decided to use Labelled Transition System to model the my network behavior (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_system). I guess that with this model I can go further. thanks.